# Can i start angular 4 on same angular 2 app seed?

Tags: javascript, angular

I just started to learn angular 2 and while i'm searching for tutorials i found what called by angular 4 with major and minor updates on angular 2 , my question if can i work on angular 4 with same tutorials and project seed for angular 2 for example [mgechev](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) seed

or should i start directly looking for angular 4 tutorials and app seeds.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the `package.json` of that linked seed project, you will see that it is up to date, with angular 4.4.4 as its dependency. So this seed project is definitely fine to use.

Angular CLI is a good approach is you are new to angular, but starting with such a seed project might be favorable if you know what you are doing.

There are some differences between ng2 and ng4, but in the end its pretty similar and backwards compatible, so most of tutorials will be probably fine. But of course its always better to look for up to date materials.

https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/blob/master/package.json

[image: seed project dependencies]

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting with Angular 4 it's a good idea to use Angular CLI. It creates a new project for you and even serves it from a web server: https://cli.angular.io/

As for the tutorials, there's not much difference between Angular 2 and Angular 4 in terms of core principles and mechanisms.